# Running Play from cygwin - only play.bat is runnable?

Tags: bash, cygwin, playframework

I'm trying to run [Play](http://www.playframework.org/) from within cygwin, and when I run `play dependencies`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/deps/DependenciesManager
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.deps.DependenciesManager...
```

`play.bat dependencies` succeeds, however. 
Even if I symlink `/usr/local/bin/play` to `.../play.bat`,I get the same error.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of play.bat suggest that it calls play with the appropriate location for the play script as first argument.

**play.bat content (batch):**

```
@echo off
"%~dp0python\python.exe" "%~dp0play" %*
```

Then the python script take the first argument (the/relative/path/to/play) and use it as its root folder to execute all the python script.

**play content (python):**

```
...
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])), 'framework', 'pym'))
...
```

By invoking `play` directly your python script get executed in your current directory.

Comment: I figured the path was getting screwed up, but I didn't understand the batch magic that was making it happen.